# When to use a mock versus a saved object in Test

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I have a function that performs a calculation on information within an object (say `myFunctionThatIWantToTest()` ).  My main question is, if a am writing a test for this function, should I save an example object to run the calculation on or make a stub?

The reason I ask is that the object the function operates on contains a complicated big structure that is a result of more complicated calculations, example:

`object = functionA(object)`  updates the object by creating a big table of numbers and other results

`result = myFunctionThatIWantToTest(object)` uses that big table to get my result

I am new at TDD so this is why I am a bit unsure about how to proceed.  What do people do?  Do you save a sample object or do you make a stub.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** - Based on your recent edit to the question: use a mock.  If you use a real instance, then the assertions in your test code would depend not only on the function you're testing, but also on `functionA` having correctly put your object in the state you think it's in.

---

original answer:

The purist's answer is simple: use a mock object.  The test should not depend on any of your code except the code you're testing.

The pragmatist's answer is a bit more complicated:  You should probably use a mock, especially if you're in doubt.  But sometimes it may be ok to use a real object instance, if you can be sure that nothing in that object's code could impact the test result.  (And, of course, if that object isn't going to pull in a bunch of other code, or do things that make the test run long, etc.)

The case where I use real objects is when the object just stores data.  Zero-logic getters and setters, that's ok; anything more, probably better use a mock.  If the object contains other methods but the test doesn't use them... well, it's a grey area, but I'd lean toward using a mock.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!!  this is helpful.